# Конек-горбунок — есть ли прототип в фольклоре?

Tags: фольклор, литература

Все сказочные персонаже "Конька-горбунка" достаточно известны в фольклоре. Это и жар-птица, и рыба-кит, и  Шамаханская царица. И вот только у самого конька-горбунка, по-моему, прообраза нет. Интересно, откуда взят этот персонаж? Или это полностью изобретение Ершова?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Конёк-горбунок "ростом только в три вершка". Эта старая русская мера длины равнялась 4,4 см. 3 вершка = 13,2 см. Некоторые художники и рисуют его величиной с маленькую собачку. Но недалеко уедешь на лошадке такого размера. Дело в том, что в старину количество вершков применительно к росту человека или лошади означало сверх: для человека - сколько вершков сверх двух аршин, для коня - сверх одного. Это значит, что герой рассказа Тургенева "Муму", немой богатырь Герасим, бывший двенадцати вершков, имел рост под два метра (71 x 2 + 52,8 = 194,8 см). Рост Конька-горбунка, таким образом, в холке был равен (71 + 4,4 x 2) = 79,8 см. Не кавалерийский, конечно, конь, но всё-таки ростом с небольшого ослика или пони, на которого всё же можно сесть верхом. 
Конёк-горбунок - выдумка Ершова,аллегория настоящей дружбы.В дружбе главное - преданность и готовность прийти на помощь. Их судьбы похожи:он тоже третий в семье, и тоже "отклонение от нормы"- помесь коня, осла и верблюда(верность коня, выносливость верблюда,трудолюбие осла). За внешним уродством кроется волшебная сила и рассудительность, которой так порой не хватает Ивану.

Answer (score 2):

[Сивка-бурка, вещий каурка](http://www.kostyor.ru/tales/tale54.html), конька-горбунка очень сильно напоминает.

Answer (score 2):

В основу произведения легли народные сказки, при этом, по-видимому, не только русские, но и сказки других народов, живущих на побережье Балтийского моря; так, известна Норвежская народная сказка с практически идентичной сюжетной линией. Сказка называется «De syv folene» («Семь жеребят»). В норвежской сказке говорится о трёх сыновьях, которые должны были пасти волшебных коней короля; награда за выполненное поручение-прекрасная принцесса. В этом поручении младшему сыну помогает волшебный жеребёнок, разговаривающий человеческим языком. Известна и монгольская сказка с весьма похожим сюжетом. Подобные сюжеты есть в словацком, белорусском, украинском (в частности, закарпатском), бурятском, цыганском (кэлдэрарском) фольклоре.

(Вики)

Вообще-то это не ответ, так размышления на тему.
Чтобы дать настоящий ответ, надо бы сначала выяснить, а что оно вообще такое, этот Горбунок.   
Ну не бывает лошадей ростом в три вершка. (12 см.)
Даже если это аршин+3 вершка, все равно 85 см. (в холке) - маловато даже для пони. 
А если 2 аршина + 3 вершка - это уже в рост человека... Не то что-то тут.
Похоже, за этим коньком кроется что-то сакральное, даже табуированое... 
Чуть ли не фаллическое.

Эти подозрения тем более усиливаются, что в сказке про конькового братца, Сивку-Бурку эти мотивы уже неприкрыты. "Встань передо мною как лист перед травою". Как вы это себе представляте, стоящий(!) перед травою лист?

Comment: а может это мир, так изменился, что в простой рифме мы видим что-то фаллическое, а раньше бы и внимания не обратили. Всегда с уважением и интересом читаю ваши ответы и комментарии, но здесь как-то я с вами не согласна. Ваши подозрения по поводу листа и травы очень напоминают историю из моей юности, когда в комментариях к "Сказке о Марье Моревне" говорили, что сказка учит разврату - как это добрый молодец зашёл в шатёр, увидел спящую Марью Моревну и лёг с ней спать рядом. А чем же они там в шатре занимались? Не надо в детских сказках, пусть и взрослыми написанных, искать то, чего в них нет.

Answer (score 1):

На мой взгляд, прототипы героев сказки "Конек-Горбунок" следует искать также и в других архаичных образах, запечатленных, в частности, в кабардинской сказке "Белый альп" (которая, на мой взгляд, имеет более стройный сюжет, нежели сказка Ершова): в кабардинской сказке царю снится волшебный белый конь-альп, за которым он отправляет трех своих сыновей. Волшебного коня, выходящего из моря, находит и покоряет младший сын. Возвращаясь домой, царевич находит перо золотой птицы и хочет взять его, однако мудрый альп предостерегает своего хозяина: "Возьмешь перо - пожалеешь, не возьмешь - будешь каяться", на что царевич отвечает: "Лучше каяться, чем жалеть!" и берет перо с собой. По дороге юношу схватывают воины местного царя, который требует привезти ему саму золотую птицу. Альп помогает царевичу схватить золотую птицу, которая на самом деле - дочь морского царя. Плененная царевна наотрез отказывается выходить замуж за старого царя, однако, уступая мольбам последнего, рассказывает о средстве вернуть молодость - для этого нужно выкопать глубокий колодец и наполнить его молоком чудесных красных коров. Колодец выкопан, коров призывает сама царевна, молоко в него надоено, однако царь в нем просто тонет. Царевич, возвращаясь с царевной домой, встречает своих братьев, которые, желая завладеть чудесным конем и прекрасной девушкой, бросают его в глубокий колодец. Царю сообщают, что его младший сын погиб. Альп убегает, а царевна запирается в своих покоях и никого к себе не пускает. К ней приходить альп, сообщает, что его хозяин жив, однако для его высвобождения нужна помощь. Царевна не раздумывая отрезает свои косы, из которых делает прочную веревку, с помощью которой конь высвобождает младшего царевича. Юноша возвращается домой на белом коне, его старшие братья убегают прочь, а сам он женится на прекрасной царевне.

Итак, возвращаясь к нашей теме, проведем сравнения: прежде всего, в сказке П.П.Ершова не совсем понятно: зачем волшебный конь каждую ночь появляется в поле - чтобы просто проскакать по нему? В сказке о белом альпе все предельно ясно: море - жилище волшебного коня (тут можно вспомнить о конях Посейдона и т.д.), и он выходит из него каждый день на рассвете, чтобы за один миг трижды облететь вокруг света, искупаться в волшебном озере, поваляться на песке и снова скрыться в морской пучине. (Возможно, "волны" хлебного поля и являются слабым отражением волн морских, однако утверждать с уверенностью не могу.)

Также в сказке Ершова, на мой взгляд, "слишком много" лошадей (что, кстати, совсем не характерно для народных сказок - чаще всего в них фигурирует лишь один конь-помощник, как, например, в случае с той же Сивкой-Буркой) - здесь вам и волшебная кобылица, скачущая по полю, и два коня златогривых (введенные в сюжет, по-видимому, для красоты), и верный, хоть и некрасивый, помощник Конек-Горбунок; в сказке же о белом альпе волшебный морской скакун - это и конь, которого хочет иметь царь и за которым отправляет своих сыновей, и помощник самого настойчивого и отважного младшего сына (два в одном, если хотите, хотя, на мой взгляд, все как раз наоборот - Петр Павлович из одного сделал четырех, и не совсем удачно; возможно, П.П.Ершов "погнался" за "магичностью" числа "3" и, опять же, возможно, пытался вывести параллели: "три коня - три сына", "младший конь - неказистый горбунок - младший сын - дурак", однако данная идея не стала прозрачной и затерялась в нагромождении прочих символов сказки).

В кабардинской сказке основные антагонисты главного героя - его старшие братья (как и положено в индоевропейских историях), в сказке П.П.Ершова поначалу антагонистами вроде бы выступают старшие братья Иванушки, затем они исчезают, и на авансцену выходит царский спальник (образ, не спорю, прописан очень хорошо и запоминается благодаря своей яркости, а позднее и "заимствуется" в мультфильме "Иван-царевич и Серый волк", однако - опять-таки, на мой взгляд - во вроде бы написанной по народным канонам сказке появляется слишком много протагонистов, что данным неписаным канонам народных сказаний совсем не соответствует).

В сказке Петра Павловича похищение Жар-птицы и Царь-девицы, живущей на берегу Океана, - два по сути не связанных и разрозненных эпизода; в кабардинской сказке Золотая птица и есть сама дочь морского царя. В народной сказке подвиги главного героя следуют в логической последовательности: поиск и покорение волшебного коня > поиск и нахождение волшебной птицы, пленение царевны > испытание на себе зависти и коварства братьев и медленная смерть > спасение (воскресение) и свадьба. В сказке Ершова смысловая цепочка, на мой взгляд, полностью смазана: нахождение и покорение златогривой кобылицы "размывается" появлением новых коней, и кобылица полностью "уходит на задний план", чтобы больше не возвращаться (и подвиг Иванушки вроде бы и не выглядит подвигом...); затем Иванушка долго и мучительно вводится в царское окружение и только с этого момента вроде бы и начинаются его настоящие подвиги: Жар-птица, Царь-девица, перстень, разбивающий триаду и появляющийся ни к селу ни к городу (явно "из другой" оперы - из сказок наподобие "Златовласки", где нахождение перстня - как раз один из трех подвигов); купание в трех купелях (в сказке о белом альпе молочных колодец - вообще один из промежуточных эпизодов, а в ершовской версии занимает ключевое место, их опать-таки, слишком много - ну, любил, видать, Петр Павлович цифру "3", ну что ты сделаешь, хотя о пользе контрастных водных процедур и молочных ванн никто не спорит - отсылка на данный текст стала почти классической).

Подведем итоги: автор "Конька-Горбунка" (некоторые исследователи отказывают П.П.Ершову в авторстве этого сказки) явно использовал несколько сюжетов народных сказок - и сказки наподобие "Белого альпа" (подобный сюжет мне встретился также в одной из индийской сказок, и, уверена, он имеет еще множество вариантов) и "Сивки-Бурки", и упомянутую схожую с норвежской сказку (все три сюжета, вероятно, имеют один архаичный первоисточник), и сказки вроде "Златовласки", и сюжет русских сказок об Иванушке-дурачке, однако скомпоновать цельное и связное произведение, написанное в соответствии со строгими и стройными канонами народных сказок, на мой взгляд, автору не удалось - к великому сожалению. Новый сказочный образ Конька-Горбунка - этакая смесь жеребенка (пони ?), осла и верблюда - также вызывает лично у меня странное ощущение, поскольку ни ослы, ни верблюды не выступают ни в одной (из известных мне) русских, да и восточно- и западнославянских сказок, а "Конек" написан (вроде бы) по мотивам именно русских сказок. Поэтому "Конька-Горбунка" считаю достаточно хорошей авторской сказкой, однако "для души" предпочитаю прочесть народную сказку - того же "Белого альпа" или индийскую сказку, а на досуге надеюсь найти текст норвежской (и иже с нею) сказки.